# Can you use "core" as an adjective?

Tags: adjectives

Can you use "core" as an adjective? The sentence I'm looking at is:

> Core to our climate action journey is the continued reduction of emissions ...

Comment: I like it. But I'd be wondering if the reduction is something the journey will observe, produce, hope for, claim to consider central just for saying so? Just saying so.

Comment: Note that words don't come labelled as "noun" or "adjective". In many cases, you can't tell. And in all cases, it doesn't matter what POS you assign to it because nobody but your English teacher cares about that.

Comment: Yes you may. We refer to core objectives, core skills, core concepts. Best answered on ELL

Answer (score 1):

AHD includes an adjective sense for *core*:
[American Heritage Dictionary *core*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=core)
adjective:

1. Of basic importance; essential:
   “Virtually all cultures around the world use the word heart to describe anything **that is core, central, or foundational**”
2. Anatomy Of or relating to the muscles of the trunk of the human body: **a core workout**.

Merriam-Webster shows it as a noun, "often attributive*, i.e., a noun functioning as an adjective before another noun.
[M-W *core*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/core)

b : the muscles of the mid-region of the torso
**core muscles/strength, core exercises**

About attributive nouns:
[Thoughtco *attributive noun*](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-attributive-noun-1689012)
In English grammar, an attributive noun is a noun that modifies another noun and functions as an adjective. Also known as a noun premodifier, a noun adjunct, and a converted adjective.

**The use in the OP seems most like a simple adjective. One can substitute the adjective *central* and have the same sense:**

**Central to our climate action journey is...**

As an afterthought, if the sentence started with "The core..." (with the definite article), *core* would be a noun, and it would identify a unique item as the core. Without a definite article, I think it's an adjective that leaves room for other core components.

Comment: Thank you! Merriam-Webster did not list an adjective form for "core."

Comment: Though AHD does give an example showing a positive result for 'Tests for use after a verb (the first AHD example)' it does not include one for gradeability (?corer?). It is probably in the course of conversion, slightly behind 'fun' (where '[nothing is] more fun [than ...]' is quite common nowadays). One might expect the periphrastic comparative 'more core' to become idiomatic before the inflected comparative 'corer'.

Answer (score -1):

> Can you use "core" as an adjective?

Yes.

"Our *core* values are integrity and service."

“3 *Core* Competencies You Must Follow For Successful L&D”
https://www.lambdasolutions.net/blog/3-core-competencies-hr-must-have-for-successful-l-and-d

"Core" functions as an adjective in each of the above constructions, modifying the nouns "values" and "competencies, respectively.

Comment: Hello, ef. The fact that a modifier may occur prenominally (before the head noun) does not guarantee that it is an adjective in that usage; attributive nouns (eg football manager, boy wonder, nursery school, tungsten steel,  singles bar) are very common. Tests for use after a verb (the first AHD example above) and gradeability (?corer?) are more reliable.

Comment: Greetings, EA! Well, I never claimed that the modifier has to appear before the noun; it merely has to appear somewhere and clearly modify the noun's meaning, and usually, an adjective modifying a pronoun appears after it. Re your examples, I would parse each attributive word as an adjective (though I might hyphenate boy-wonder and call it a compound, and I might put an apostrophe after singles, and call it a plural noun, possessive case. I don't see how the idea of an "attributive noun" differs in any way from an "adjective" vis-à-vis function. Seems to be a distinction without a difference.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/core) senses 5, and then 2b  [under British English], label 'core group' as  [NOUN noun], and 'core meaning' as  "['core' used] as modifier", still under the _noun_ classification. The fact that 'more core / corer' and 'less core' are at best rare argues that conversion to adjective has not taken place. And certainly 'football' in 'football match / manager' would be classed as an adjective by very few grammarians.